# My TreeView in my ListView prevents scrolling the ListView during mouse over TreeView. (XAML)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview, treeview

My ListView contains a successfully implemented TreeView as an item source in one of my columns. However once expanded the user will need to move the mouse off of the TreeView items in order to scroll the ListView. This feels unnatural for my program and I would like to find a way to scroll the ListView even if the mouse is still over the expanded TreeView.

Here is the CellTemplate for the TreeView:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="workFlow:AssemblyModels">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TreeView Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="0"                                                      
                      Background="Transparent"
                      Focusable="False">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Product Line List" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductLine}" 
                              Background="Transparent">
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance that can be provided to fix this issue.

James

Comment: You mean with the mouse wheel? Or with the cursor keys?

Tbh, the concept of an entire tree in a row and multiple trees in the list seems awkward to me. I can see a tree / list hybrid, but that's essentially one tree in the view.

If you have one tree per item and you are trying to scroll with the scroll bars, that should work, as should the mouse wheel if you are over the list portion.

You'd have to figure out how you want scrolling to behave when the user is on the tree. There are a whole bunch of weird scenarios. Expanded / Not expanded, parent selected / child selected, etc.

Comment: Yes, with the mouse wheel. So basically I have a huge list of information that has to be stored in that specific cell for each row. Storing the data raw into the table like that hinders navigation of the table as a whole. I tried multiple methods that I was able to get working, however this was the cleanest looking method. Problem is that when the mouse is hovering over the expanded tree the mouse wheel scroll does not work. The user would need to mouse off the tree to scroll the rest of the table.

Comment: Yes, the window that the mouse is over is going to get the wheel events. Standard Windows behavior. If you want to do what you are after, catch the wheel events in the tree and send them over to the list. You'll need to use the Preview events though so you can block the tree from scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will work on implementing your suggestion. If I get it working properly I will post a full solution to the problem I ran into.